# "Require SSL" on databases created via DatabaseClusterEngine

Tags: aws-cdk

Is it possible to "require SSL" on an Aurora database created using the AWS CDK? We've enabled encryption, but that is only "at rest", and we're also required to encrypt "in transit" and are being flagged by a security monitor because the database does not "require SSL".

Here is the code we use to set up the database:

```
const cluster = new rds.DatabaseCluster(scope, 'TheDB', {
defaultDatabaseName: dbName,
engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraPostgres({ version: rds.AuroraPostgresEngineVersion.VER_13_7 }),
credentials: {
  username: dbUser,
  password: pgPasswordSecret.secretValue,
},
instanceProps: {
  securityGroups: [securityGroup],
  instanceType: primaryPostgresInstanceType(),
  vpcSubnets: {
    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_NAT,
  },
  vpc,
},
storageEncrypted: true,
backup: {
  retention: Duration.days(15),
},
```

})

Answer (score 2):

The solution (from https://gitter.im/awslabs/aws-cdk?at=5e2ab552f196225bd64b7581) is to pass a `parameterGroup` when creating the database cluster, setting `rds.force_ssl` to `'1'`:

```
  const postgresVersion = rds.AuroraPostgresEngineVersion.VER_13_7

  const parameterGroup = new rds.ParameterGroup(scope, 'ClusterParameterGroup', {
    engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraPostgres({ version: postgresVersion}),
    parameters: {
      'rds.force_ssl': '1',
    },
  })

  const cluster = new rds.DatabaseCluster(scope, 'TheDB', {
    ...
    parameterGroup,
    ...
  })
```